# Android RecyclerView LayoutManager Exception in Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

My app crashes anytime i try to access a fragment that displays a cardview using RecyclerView. The app works on a single activity, but doesn't work using fragments. I get this error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)

Please help.
Here is the Recyclerfragment

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private List<Person> persons;
private RecyclerView rv;
private Context context;
private RVAdapter adapter;

public RecyclerViewActivity()
{

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    rv=(RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv);
    adapter = new RVAdapter(getActivity(),initializeData());
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    return layout;
}


private static List<Person> initializeData(){
    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma));
    persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.lavery));
    persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.lillie));


  return persons;
}


}
```

Here is the Adapter

```
Public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Person> data = Collections.emptyList();

public  RVAdapter(Context context,List<Person> data)
{
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;

}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
   //View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup,false);
    PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
    personViewHolder.personName.setText(data.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.personAge.setText(data.get(i).age);
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(data.get(i).photoId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CardView cv;
    TextView personName;
    TextView personAge;
    ImageView personPhoto;

    PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
        personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),personName.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

And here is the Persons Object am trying to add.

```
class Person {
String name;
String age;
int photoId;




Person(String name, String age, int photoId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.photoId = photoId;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you post more of your error log please, specifically the exception? If it's a `NullPointerException` for instance, it may be because you are using `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv)` for your `RecyclerView`, and not `layout.findViewById(R.id.rv)`

Comment: Hi @PPartisan here is the full error 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.talagbe.swipetab, PID: 1842
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
            at com.talagbe.swipetab.RecyclerViewActivity.onCreateView(RecyclerViewActivity.java:43)

Comment: Thank you @PPartisan, it worked layout.findviewById(). Thank you very much,I can't mark you answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rv=(RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv);`
Here is your problem. You are calling findViewById() on Activity and the activity does not find your `R.id.rv` in it's layout and it's returning null. Supposing that `R.id.rv` is inside `R.layout.fragment_home` you should replace that line with:
`rv=(RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rv);`.

Comment: Thank you @PPartisan, already gave the clue. Thank you for the detail explanation

Comment: Glad to help, welcome to Android! "May the odds be ever in your favour!"

Answer (score 1):

When you `inflate` a `layout` file in `onCreateView()`, you should use `findViewById()` on the `View` returned.

With that in mind, try switching `rv=(RecyclerView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rv);` for `rv=(RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.rv);`